# Setting Recursive tag ON does not searching sub folders for .NET projects

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I am a newbie to doxygen tool. I've followed the doxygen configuration guide for generating a HTML document out of my C# source files. I am able to generate the HTML output, but I identified that it is generating output of the files that exists in the selected source folder only, where as the files present inside the sub directories of the source folder are skipped/ignored. Per help guide, I've checked the "Recursive" option in the wizard. Is there anything still we need to configure?
Could anyone help me out for resolving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Regards
Badri

Comment: Which version of doxygen? DId you use the doxywizard?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63450971/1657886

Comment: Hi Albert, Thanks for commenting. The version of doxygen I am using is 1.8.19 and it's doxywizard.

Comment: @albert, After following your link [link](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7951), I tried to launch doxy file from command prompt and it is working. It is able to browse the sub directories. Just I would like to know, will there be any fix for wizard soon..

Comment: I've seen a remark, some time ago, that the maintainer would see whether or not he could make a new version, but so far I've not heard / seen anything.

Comment: A new doxygen release 1.8.20 is available where this problem has been fixed

Comment: @albert That's great! Thank you for quick response.